# breaking a one table in to several small tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am developing HRM system using php/mysql. There is one table that has more than 30 coloums. Since there is no data repeating I didnt break it in to other tables. But after I design the designing part of the system, coustomer wanted to store data part by part. Now there are 6 form submittion instead of one form. But the problem is now I have to use one table for insearting six form's data.

I can continue this as I do. But I want to know whether it is technically ok. or do I want to break one table (35 coloums) in to 6 tables?

please share your thoughts.

Comment: well if the one table is correctly formed (ACID), dont break it only because you enter the data in 6 different pages/forms. Save the data in php (session, cache, whatsoever) and store it when user is done. Of course, if user can pause entry and resume... splitting the data entry would be easier, not necc. better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many form submissions that condense inte one table is not strange and should not be a reason to split the table.
30 columns in a single table should not matter either as log as the table is normalized

Splitting the table based on some UI feature would probably de-normalize the database